# Joins supported by Hibernate Query Language (HQL)

Tags: hibernate, join, hql

i'm new to Hibernate framework, basically i've experience in using joins in mysql. But does'nt know whether all the joins supported by other databases will support in hql.

can anyone please tell me which all joins are there in hibernate from the following below joins.

1. INNER JOIN
2. LEFT JOIN
3. RIGHT JOIN
4. OUTER JOIN
5. FULL JOIN
6. FULL OUTER JOIN
7. LEFT OUTER JOIN
8. RIGHT OUTER JOIN
9. CROSS JOIN
10. LEFT JOIN EXCLUDING INNER JOIN
11. RIGHT JOIN EXCLUDING INNER JOIN
12. OUTER JOIN EXCLUDING INNER JOIN

Answer (score 1):

The best starting point would be the documentation. In the section [16.3. Associations and joins](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-joins), we can see, that for querying, based on HQL we have:

> The supported join types are borrowed from ANSI SQL:
>
> - inner join
> - left outer join
> - right outer join
> - full join (not usually useful)

And that's pretty it. Because we are working on the abstractinal model, all the 'specific' JOIN types defined by DB providers are not supported

Also you can check the Criterion [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/envers/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/CriteriaSpecification.html#LEFT_JOIN), to see predefined joins 'const':  `FULL_JOIN`, `INNER_JOIN`, `LEFT_JOIN`, used for Criteria API *(e.g. Criteria.LEFT_JOIN)*